# Flutter: Create unique values from Firestore for dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that is being populated from Firestore with this code.

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('field_management')
        .orderBy('cultivar_name')
        .get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
          width: 15.0,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
      return DropdownButton(
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            cultivarDropdownValue =
                newValue.toString();
          });
        },
        hint: Text(cultivarDropdownValue),
        items: snapshot.data!.docs
            .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: document['cultivar_name'],
            child:
            Text(document['cultivar_name']),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
  ),
```

How can I create a unique list from the Firestore data to avoid duplicates in the dropdown menu?

I have tried adding items to the list in the `initState()` method, still received all the values from the collection (code below). Not sure what else I can try to make this work.

```
addDropDownItems() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('field_management')
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      for (dynamic document in snapshot.docs) {
        if (!blockList.contains(document.data())) {
          blockList.add(document.data());
        }
      }
      print('block list: ${blockList}');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post ([How can I distinct a complex object list in DART](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347425/how-can-i-distinct-a-complex-object-list-in-dart)), which solved the problem.

I made use of the [darq](https://pub.dev/packages/darq) package and just had to add this line above my print statement:

```
var uniqueList = blockList.distinct();
```